# How can I "undispose" in knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a view model like this:

```
var myViewModel = function (){
    var self= this;
    self.someObservable = ko.observable();

    var someObservableSubscription = self.someObservable.subscribe(function(){
        //some stuff including a different ajax 'Get'
    });

    self.ajaxPost = function(){
        //some ajax
        //on done call this method
        cleanModel();
    }

    var cleanModel = function(){
        someObservableSubscription.dispose();
        self.someObservable('');

        //now i want to resubscribe to my function here
        //this is where I need help

}
```

Do i have to do another `self.someObservable.subscribe(function(){ //some function})` again?  I want to clean the value in the variable without losing my observable, but if I clean it while it has a subscription it will try to make that ajax call with a null value.

I guess another way to fix this would be to wrap my subscription functions in an `if` that checks that the value of the observable is valid before making doing anything.  Which of these would be best/are there any other ways to do this?

Comment: I would do the if-test.

Comment: It's definitely cleaner to validate in the subscribe then it is to add/remove the subscribe.

Comment: thanks!  someone provide an answer and i will accept it

Comment: You could just use a named function in your `subscribe` instead of an anonymous function. So `self.someObservable.subscribe(somefunction)`

Comment: I think the `if` method is probably the way to go here

Comment: Amit I would very much say this this is not the same as the one.  It is similar, but the purpose of mine is to only ignore a subscription while a value is reset to null.  The `if` wrappers make the most sense here, because the user could potentially enter a value of "0" in the input, and this handles that in addition to handling the "cleaning" of the value

Comment: @USER_8675309 You can post your own answer. I think your last comment is about right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than calling `dispose` and then "`undispose`" <--- (that one is made up), the correct way to handle the changing value is to wrap the inside of the subscribe function in an `if` statement.

Example below:

```
var someObservableSubscription = self.someObservable.subscribe(function(){
    if (self.someObservable() > 0) {
        //some stuff including a different ajax 'Get'
    }
});
```

Comment: The function passed to `subscribe` can take the new value as a param: `...subscribe(function(val) { ...`  This saves you the processing effort of then 'unwrapping' that observable *within * the `subscribe` handler. [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables)

Comment: I generally label this param as `newValue` and do checks on it, especially when it only requires one value to be checked.  A lot of my ajax calls require 3 or 4 parameters, so I try to use `self.observableName` on these `if` wrappers in order to keep what I am doing straight.  thank you for the input